# Windows Terminal profile or action to open 4 tabs (2x2) in a new tab?

Tags: terminal, windows-terminal

I want to create an action or a new profile which opens 4 new tabs in a 2x2 layout. But I've several issues with this:

My profile just won't open inline with the terminal but always in a new window.

I cant get it to render a 2x2 grid but a 1x2 with another break in the last tile.

[image: 1x2 grid]

Here is the profile I've created. I've tried the same commandline with the `newTab` action with similar results.

```
{
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005}",
    "name": "myProfile",
    "commandline": "wt new-tab -p \"Foo\" ; 
                       split-pane -H -p \"Bar\"  ; 
                       split-pane -V -p \"Baz\" ; 
                       split-pane -H -p \"Git Bash\" -d \"C:\\foo\""
}
```

For better readability I've added linebreaks to the code above. they are not in my configuration

---

Update 1:

I was able to solve the issue with the 2x2 pane layout by using the `move-focus` command. I think this is a preview feature only atm.

```
{
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005}",
    "name": "myProfile",
    "commandline": "wt new-tab -p \"Foo\" ;                        
                       split-pane -V -p \"Bar\"  ; 
                       move-focus left ;                       
                       split-pane -H -p \"Baz\" ; 
                       move-focus up ;
                       move-focus right ;
                       split-pane -H -p \"Git Bash\" -d \"C:\\foo\""
}
```

Comment: Did you try opening with Powershell?  Works here. wt -p "Command Prompt" `; split-pane -p "Windows PowerShell" `; split-pane -H wsl.exe   From:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=powershell

Comment: @John well. you are only using 3 tabs => won't fix my 2x2 layout issue. aside from that it does also open a new window

Comment: The command I used has two tabs (side by side) and one tab below right. It could be set up for four workspaces.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying? I'm trying to create a 2x2 grid layout. 4 Panes all equally sized. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: I think you might be correct. I tried 4 panes (split-pane -H and -V) but I still wound up with 3 panes. Sorry, but it looks like my idea will not work for you. I will work on it some more tomorrow.

Comment: This SO post might be helpful, but more work than a simple command. Still, it is worth reviewing.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61878143/how-to-open-windows-terminal-with-4-panes

Comment: You are right that the `move-focus` is only in Preview at the moment. But I'd recommend that you move that information to the "answer".

Comment: `wt -w 0 new-tab` will create new tab in the current window

Answer (score 5):

This is 4x4 profile in the same window:

```
{
  "commandline": "wt -w 0 new-tab -p \"Foo\" ; split-pane -V -p \"Bar\"  ; move-focus left ; split-pane -H -p \"Baz\" ; move-focus up ; move-focus right ; split-pane -H -p \"Git Bash\" -d \"C:\\git\"",
  "guid": "{e4554b48-406d-4615-98a0-fadd035e6cac}",
  "hidden": false,
  "name": "4x4"
}
```